# Diferença na utilização Indice Unique e Unique Constraint no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, restrição-único

Gostaria de saber qual o comportamento/diferenças entre um **Indice Unique** e **Unique Constraints** para o **MySQL** ?

Muitos devem pensar que isso não faz diferença no banco de dados, mas faz!
E não só para o DBA/Administrador, mas para os desenvolvedores também pois pode influenciar como um código é escrito.

---

Como referência do que pode ser tão diferente e que estou interessado em saber, segue abaixo um link de como é em um banco **Informix** , mas no **MySQL** como funciona?

Link, situação similar em outro engine: [Diferença na utilização Indice Unique e Unique Constraint no Informix?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/diferenca-na-utilizacao-indice-unique-e-unique-constraint-no-informix)

Comment: possível duplicata de [Quando usar uma unique constraints vs indices únicos no Oracle?](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/515/quando-usar-uma-unique-constraints-vs-indices-unicos-no-oracle)

Comment: Estamos discutindo a validade desse tipo de pergunta aqui: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/289/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-com-podem-ter-multiplas-respostas

Comment: Nao considero esta pergunta duplicada pois sao objetivos diferentes, onde uma explica pontualmente a utilizacao do recurso em um banco especifico e a outra tende a comparar a disponibilidade destes mesmos recursos entre diferentes banco de dados , o que fara toda difererca para qualquer desenvolvedor que trabalhe com sistemas que suporte multi-banco de dados e DBAs que precisam administrar esta variedade toda.

Comment: Duplicada não parece mesmo, a questão é se ela é ampla ou não. O pessoal não está entendendo para que serve o voto sobre a **duplicação exata**

Comment: Se tivesse especificado uma engine de banco de dados essa seria uma pergunta *legítima* para nosso formato; mas como você deixa em aberto para várias engines diferentes acaba sendo *amplo demais*. Com relação a marcação de duplicado, eu discordo, a pergunta já feita responde apenas parte da pergunta atual.

Comment: @talles, por favor me explica, como fazer uma pergunta de comparação de comportamento especificos colocando apenas um engine de banco de dados? Se eu questionar apenas um terei uma resposta incompleta assim como teve na do oracle que vocês dizem ser duplicada. No caso especifico da outra questão/Oracle, como a resposta já foi aceita, como faço para conseguir a informação que preciso, que não está lá na resposta? Posso até solicitar mais informações no comentário, as não boto fé de que após aceita a questão, alguém mais vá adicionar novas informações... posso até tentar, mas...

Comment: Bom, mas antes que fechem a questão como duplicada... então vou editar ela, deixar especifico como querem que seja... e vou criar outras para cada engine.

Comment: Para complementar: [Como Manipular Perguntas Duplicadas](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/)(en)

Comment: Para deixar claro, o texto no comentário acima é para mostrar que esta pergunta **de forma nenhuma** é duplicada. Vamos reabri-la.

Comment: Existe algum problema a ser resolvido? Ou a pergunta é apenas existencial? Gostaria de ver pessoas com problemas a serem resolvidos, e ajudar essas pessoas a resolverem seus problemas.

Comment: Eu (autor da pergunta) estou no aguardo de uma resposta técnica e objetiva a pergunta. Que é o entendimento de funcionamento da questão no MySQL. (mas como o SOpt ainda é fechado, particularmente não espero que todas as perguntas aqui tenham respostas boas e validas de imediato).

Comment: @ceinmart eu particularmente acho que a citação da outra questão poluiu a sua, só o link já seria suficiente embora ainda assim acho desnecessário, já que a sua questão é objetiva e válida. Provavelmente a resposta deve conter o comportamento sobre os diferentes _engines_ de armazenamento.

Comment: hmmm. ok @Diego, concordo... vou editar a pergunta e deixar apenas o link. (é que quando escrevi a 1a vez era tudo em uma pergunta só...e ai por isso de uma discussão danada aqui)

Answer (score 10):

No MySQL **é a mesma coisa**.

`ALTER TABLE tabela ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE KEY` é a mesma coisa que `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX`

De acordo com a [documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

KEY e INDEX são sinônimos.

> KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX. The key attribute PRIMARY KEY can
>   also be specified as just KEY when given in a column definition. This
>   was implemented for compatibility with other database systems.

A nomenclatura para **índices** é usar o mesmo nome do primeiro campo, e se já existir, adicionar _2, _3 e assim por diante.

> In MySQL, the name of a PRIMARY KEY is PRIMARY. For other indexes, if
>   you do not assign a name, the index is assigned the same name as the
>   first indexed column, with an optional suffix (_2, _3, ...) to make it
>   unique. You can see index names for a table using SHOW INDEX FROM
>   tbl_name.

Para comprovar você mesmo, execute o dump da estrutura da tabela, e vai ver que tanto para **index** ou **constraint**, é a mesma coisa.

Mas se ainda quiser tirar a prova definitiva, compare o **schema** do banco, e verá que não existe diferença.

Answer (score 6):

**KEY** e **INDEX** são sinônimos em MySQL.
 Eles querem dizer a mesma coisa. No banco de dados você usaria índices para melhorar a velocidade de recuperação de dados. 
Um índice é tipicamente criado em colunas usadas em cláusulas `JOIN, WHERE e ORDER BY`.
**Importante :** 
Você só pode ter uma chave primária por tabela, mas várias restrições exclusivas.

Há uma diferença muito importante entre um Indice Unique (MySQL responder a uma "restrição de unicidade") e uma chave primária no MySQL.
*Dê uma olhada nisso:*
Cria uma tabela t com um `indice unique` nas columnas `a,b` (A combinaçao das columnas a,b deve identificar unicamente qualquer tupla na tabela, certo?)

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  a int,
  b int,
  c int,
  UNIQUE KEY a (a,b)
);
```

Agora vamos inserir dados:

```
mysql> insert into t (a,b,c)values(1,2,3);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into t (c)values(1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into t (a,c)values(1,1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into t (b,c)values(1,1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into t (b,c)values(1,1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into t (a,b,c)values(1,2,3);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'a'
mysql> select * from t;
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |    3 |
| NULL | NULL |    1 |
|    1 | NULL |    1 |
| NULL |    1 |    1 |
| NULL |    1 |    1 |
+------+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Um índice exclusivo cria uma restrição de tal forma que todos os valores no índice devem ser distintos. Um erro ocorre se você tentar adicionar uma nova linha com um valor de chave que corresponda a uma linha existente. Esta restrição não se aplica a valores NULL, exceto para o mecanismo de armazenamento `BDB`. Para outros motores, um índice `UNIQUE` permite valores NULL múltiplo para colunas que podem conter `NULL`.

*Performance* **Indice Unique** *vs* **Unique Constraints**: 
Com `MyISAM` como o engine, não deve haver uma diferença de desempenho entre o **Indice Unique** *vs* **Unique Constraints**.
O `MyISAM` não trata eles de forma diferente.
Se você estava usando o engine `InnoDB`, no entanto, haveria uma diferença,porque o `InnoDB` armazena os dados em ordem de chave primária.

Answer (score 0):

**A unique key:** garante a unicidade de informações na sua tabela. (Geralmente chaves únicas também pode ter registros nulos, por isso não podem ser chave primária.)

**A primary key:**  Pode ser utilizada para relacionamentos de foreign key com outras tabelas. (Não pode conter registros nulos mas pode se usar autoincrement).

Comment: Mas não foi isso que ele perguntou.