# Criar campo unique Android Studio

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Sou iniciante no desenvolvimento android e estou tentando criar uma tabela no sqlite onde o valor do email será único. Só que o aplicativo está permitindo cadastrar emails iguais.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE usuario (" +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
                "email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE," +
                "senha TEXT NOT NULL);";
            db.execSQL(sql);
            Toast.makeText(UsuarioRepository.this.contexto, "Tabela criada com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (SQLException ex){
            Toast.makeText(UsuarioRepository.this.contexto, "Erro ao criar tabela: "+ex, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Se sua aplicação permite cadastrar e-mails iguais mas sua tabela não permite então o erro deve estar em sua aplicação. Outra coisa que pode estar ocorrendo é que alguma caractere espaço no início ou fim do e-mail pode estar diferenciando e-mails aparentemente iguais. Remova eventuais espaços desnecessários.

Answer (score 0):

Tem um exemplo bacana neste Link: [Diferença na utilização Indice Unique e Unique Constraint no MySQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/793/diferen%C3%A7a-na-utiliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-indice-unique-e-unique-constraint-no-mysql)

No seu create table siga este exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE `phone` (
    `id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `country` DECIMAL(5,0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `area` DECIMAL(5,0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `number` DECIMAL(8,0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `extension` DECIMAL(5,0) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `ix_phone` (`country`, `area`, `number`, `extension`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```